# Leave trail while doing drag n drop in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am currently trying to implement a simple android application which lists all the apps installed on the system and allows the user to rearrange the list using drag and drop interaction.

I want to implement a simple UI feature which leaves a trail of the shape of icon which is being dragged on the screen. My question is that is it possible to get the icon shape in program? If yes, please guide me towards how to retrieve it.

If you want to draw parallels, take a look at [mouse cursor trails](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Pointer+trails)